# Is there a special place for non-owl familiars at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

We know of the owlery, is there a rattery and cattery?  A toadery (knottery?)?

Why did the owls have to have a separate place anyway?  They seemed to have no problem getting into any room, eg the Great Hall for mail delivery.

Comment: Owls had a special place because owl pellets are disgusting.  Ron, Neville, and Hermione all seemed to be able to keep their pets with them in Gryffindor Tower.

Comment: What Legion said. If you ever kept a pet bird (parrot?) you'd never need to ask :)  [ then again, rats? ewwww ]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is no room equipped for pets only. The owlery is there because the school provides owls for the post, and, as @legion600 points out, owl droppings are a bit disgusting, so people who own owls can send them there to rest.

There must be special places (toilets) for cats inside the castle for when it's raining, and the grounds are big enough for the rest of the time. The house-elfs must be the ones cleaning those places, though, not the students, who appear to neglect most domestic aspects of their life at Hogwarts.

Comment: "There must be special places (toilets) for cats inside the castle" what? Why would cats be kept in the toilets? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @RedCaio litter boxes!