# Did JKR ever mention characters' pets/familiars outside of 7 HP books?

Tags: harry-potter, animals

We see several students who attended Hogwarts during Harry's time having their pets/familiars described in 7 Harry Potter books (Hermione's Kneazle, Ron's Homo Animagus Ratus, Harry's owl, Neville's toad, Ginny's pygmy puff).

However, a great deal of named students aren't mentioned as owning a pet in the 7 main books.

**Did JKR add to the known pets set in ancillary canon materials?** (3 extra books, interviews, her web site, or Pottermore).

I'm only interested in pets of *named* characters who were students in Hogwarts in Harry's time in school (in any grade), not generic "some 2d year's giant sloth".

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Pets

Comment: I've been through the wikia, fantastic beast and pottermore. I can't see any more pets owned by named **students**. There's a few new pets owned by other characters but that doesn't meet your criteria...

Comment: Crookshanks is a *half*-Kneazle half-cat.

Comment: Could you also count Rons' 2 Pet owls, Errol and Pigwidgeon? ( more so Pig as he was actually Rons) Edit: Woops misread.

Comment: Does Ginny's basilisk count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Did JKR add to the known pets set in ancillary canon materials?**

No.

I checked through *FBAWTFT*, *TTOBTB* (Babbity Rabbity might qualify as a pet in a way, but she is more an Animagus than an animal), and Pottermore -- Familiars (JKR says Mrs Norris is the closest to a traditional familiar, not pet, than any in the series) and The First 40, meaning the first 40 students in Harry's year. And, finally, I wracked my brain! Nothing came to mind, so I called it at that.

Comment: I'd like to note for the record that this is the shortest answer I have ever given on this site for a Harry Potter question \:D/